# How can I make the entire parent element of an anchor clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have almost achieved what I am looking to but the page is reloading twice after I have injected the code. **The reload is undesirable.**

```
 <script>

 $("#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1548947018047_6823").click(function() {
 window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
 return false;
  });

 </script>
```

The URL to the page: https://goodbrother.squarespace.com/blog/
The top image div titled "whos who in a production crew" is the div using this code.

Comment: Chain this to the end of your statement: `.css({"display":"block","min-height":100%"});`

Comment: @zer00ne . Tried this but it broke the code.  It looked like this when i tried your suggestion. <script>
  $("#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1548947018047_6823").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
  return false;
    
    .css({"display":"block","min-height":100%"});
});

</script>

Comment: The site isn't loading. Please show your HTML here.

Comment: Remove **`; return false;`** then chain the segment to the end parenthesis,

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an array with `find('a')`. You need to specify a single element. It might work with `find('a')[0]`, but you'd be better off putting a class on your anchor and targeting that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by adding a class to the "a"

```
<script>

 $("#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1548947018047_6823").click(function() {
 window.location = $(this).find("a.image-overlay").attr("href"); 
 return false;
  });

   </script>
```